# Change Tomcat's Charset.defaultCharset in windows

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, character-encoding, tomcat6

I'm using tomcat 6.0.32 in windows 7.
Inside a very simple servlet, inside the init method, I'm printing:

```
System.out.println(Charset.defaultCharset());
```

The output is:

```
windows-1253
```

As far as I understand this is how tomcat start's in the JVM since I'm printing the same in standalone java class and I get "UTF8" as a response.

So, how can I change this to UTF-8?

thanks

Comment: did you try `request.getCharacterEncoding();` ? See what it prints, Anyway you can change the character encoding.. but it varies depends on the requirement. Have look at this wiki page http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding#Q1

Comment: I cant access request since I'm working inside the init method. In any case this is not a request-repsonse issue since I need to have UTF8 encoding in order to read files and not to send response in UTF8 encoding.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Just create a **setenv.bat** file inside the TOMCAT/bin directory with the following contents:

```
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dfile.encoding=UTF8"
```

Comment: Is the correct configuration -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 or -Dfile.encoding=UTF8?

I think that it should be UTF-8

Comment: The correct is as described in the answer, i.e. UTF8 - check these two: 1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031877/jvm-property-dfile-encoding-utf8-or-utf-8  2)http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html

Answer (score 16):

You may also add this setting in the Tomcat 7.0 windows service manager.

[image: screenshot]

from [Dr James Bayley's blog](http://blog.jamesbayley.com/2013/09/09/tomcat-7-on-windows-is-not-utf-8-by-default/)

Comment: This setting works for me.I have one more question is this setting requires only in windows os or we need to define this in linux also?

Answer (score 6):

For Tomcat running as a Windows service neither %JAVA_OPTS% and neither setenv.bat answers works in my case.

I set the option "-Dfile.encoding=UTF8" in registry:

"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\tomcatstackTomcat\Parameters\Java --> Options*

Then it works.

Answer (score 4):

Try setting the (Windows) environment variable `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` to `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` and start the `Tomcat Server`.

Will get more idea from this link:
[Setting the default Java character encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361975/setting-the-default-java-character-encoding)

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working. Setting -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 is the correct approach but I don't thin that tomcat is appending JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS to JAVA_OPTS. In any case I found the solution. Check below.