# Insert into DB non-English characters with Spring 4 + Hibernate 4

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, encoding

I have Spring 4 + Hibernate 4 + MySQL web application. I need initialize DB tables when app are starting. For this goal I use `import.sql` file and set Hibernate `hbm2ddl.auto` to `create`. When Hibernate execute requests I have hieroglyphs in DB. I try use

```
<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/foxrest_db?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;characterSetResults=UTF-8" />
```

for connection, but it has no effect.

I think Spring open files with standard system environment encoding (in my case it's Windows 8.1, encoding: win1251), that's why all Hibernate configurations has no effect.

**My question is:**

1.How can I fix this?

2.If I will use PostgreSQL in future what I will change in DB connection or another configs?

Here is my sources:

**spring.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.foxresult" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url"  value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/foxrest_db" />
        <property name="username" value="lekarto" />
        <property name="password" value="1" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

</beans>
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCachingRegionFactory</property>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.default_cache_concurrency_strategy">transactional</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**import.sql**

```
INSERT INTO `departments` (`name`) VALUES ('Developers'), ('QA'), ('Managers'), ('Support');
INSERT INTO `employees` (`first_name`, `last_name`, `salary`, `sex`, `department_id`) VALUES ('Sergey', 'Fedorov', '100', 1, '1'), ('Иван', 'Демидов', '120', 1, '1'), ('الحسيب', 'عبد', '140', 1, '2'), ('Angelina', 'Feofilaktova', '160', 0, '3'), ('湧', '阮', '180', 0, '3'), ('Test', 'Ivanovna', '180', 0, NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the character encoding property for the JVM needs to be set.

Have you tried starting the Java App with this:
`java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`

If you are using Tomcat, then you may have to set this System property in one of the Tomcat's (catalina) script files.

Note: In past I have used only ISO-8559-1. both the Java app, and the Database were set to ISO-8559-1

UPDATE:

If maven surefire plugin is being used, then system property should be given according to this link:
http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/system-properties.html

Note that the website mentions special case for JVM system properties:
`<argLine>-Djava.endorsed.dirs=...</argLine>`

Comment: I try use this solution: http://javacimrman.blogspot.ru/2011/07/hibernate-importsql-encoding-when.html . It's didn't help. I think your advise is equal, isn't it?

Comment: The approach seems fine, but I haven't set encoding property in that way before.
The site mentions `UTF8` , but I think it should be `UTF-8`

Comment: I try change `UTF8` to `UTF-8` and nothing happens. Also I try add these parameter to `catalina.bat` for My Tomcat 8 as as has been said here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738794/add-jvm-options-in-tomcat and it didn't help. I try both variants: `CATALINA_OPTS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` and `JAVA_OPTS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11342884/change-tomcats-charset-defaultcharset-in-windows this solutions was useful, but I don't think that this is a best way. I don't want change configurations of my Tomcat or another server. I think the best way is keep all needed configs in my own application if it possible.