# Non ascii characters in CustomAuthenticator and/or CustomLoginModule

Tags: java, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I am using MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.1 (7.1.0.00.20150913-2345) and I am using Java adapters and I have a custom login module with a custom authenticator and my code resembles [this](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/authentication-security/custom-authenticator-login-module/). In my case I have some non-ascii strings. For example:

In CustomAuthenticator instead of :

```
public AuthenticationResult processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, boolean isAccessToProtectedResource) throws IOException,   ServletException {
    ...
    response.getWriter()
      .print("{\"authStatus\":\"required\", \"errorMessage\":\"Please enter username and password\"}");
    ...
}
```

I have:

```
public AuthenticationResult processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, boolean isAccessToProtectedResource) throws IOException,   ServletException {
    ...
    response.getWriter()
      .print("{\"authStatus\":\"required\", \"errorMessage\":\"ユーザー名とパスワードを入力してください\"}");
    ...
}
```

In CustomLoginModule in `login` I have some exceptions with non-ascii strings:

```
public boolean login(Map<String, Object> authenticationData) {
    ...
   　// Invalid credentials
    throw new RuntimeException("有効なユーザーIDとパスワードを入力してください");
}
```

When calling the adapter from an iOS native app: In Mac OSX it works great but the production server is in Windows and the iPad app receives the `errorMessage` as garbled text (mojibake 文字化け). Is there a way I can solve this?

---

In addition I have some non-ascii data in userIdentity object and when I try to access it in the Java Adapter it is garbled too:

```
@POST
@Produces("application/json")
@Path("/enter")
@OAuthSecurity(scope="MyRealm")
public Response enter(){
    SecurityAPI security = serverAPI.getSecurityAPI();
    String displayName = security.getSecurityContext().getUserIdentity().getDisplayName();
    // At this point displayName is garbled text when server is in windows. in OSX is OK.
}
```

What is weird is that I have another javascript adapter (that shares the same custom authenticator and login module) and getting the info from there is OK:

```
// Javascript Adapter
function myProcedure(p){
    var user = WL.Server.getActiveUser();
    // user.displayName is OK in windows and OSX
}
```

It looks like serialization of user data is buggy? Does anybody know if this is really a bug or a a mistake in some settings?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this could actually be due to the application server encoding.
See if the following helps: [IBM Worklight - Error charset/encoding in data response from webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32497199/ibm-worklight-error-charset-encoding-in-data-response-from-webservice/32499934#32499934)

If the remote server is WebSphere Liberty, locate the jvm.options file and add the following:

-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
-Duser.language=en
-Duser.country=US

If the remote server WebSphere ND, there is an Admin panel where you can set the encoding at. Consult with the WebShere documentation: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTJ_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/xrun_jvm.html

If the remote server is Tomcat: [Change Tomcat's Charset.defaultCharset in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11342884/change-tomcats-charset-defaultcharset-in-windows)

Comment: Thanks!, let me try these and will report later :)